# How do I cherry-pick the active_support for 5.seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to use the ActiveSupport extensions `3600.seconds` syntax in a plain Ruby file but I'm having trouble finding the right ActiveSupport file to require.

As far as I can work out [from the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time-constructors), I need to `require "active_support/core_ext/date/calculations"`. That doesn't seem to do it though

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `seconds' for 3600:Fixnum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In activesupport that goes with Rails 3.1 this extension is in `active_support/core_ext/numeric/time`. You can see it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb).